# JavaNullPointerException on calling function

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception

I get an error when I call a function in java.
The return type is void, and I just call it and display a string inside.

Here is the call of the bugging function :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String findDevicesByCriteria(@Valid @ModelAttribute Device device, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel) {
    if (isCriteriaEmpty(device)) {
        uiModel.addAttribute("criteriaEmptyWarning", "error_search_criteria_empty");
        return ViewConstants.DEVICE_SEARCH_VIEW;
    }
    identityService.searchDevices(device.getSerialNumber(), device.getOwner().getSiteName(), device.getIpAdress(), device.getInstallDate(), device.getEndDate()); // the error come from here

    return ViewConstants.DEVICE_SEARCH_VIEW;
}
```

The prototype in the interface of the bugging function :

```
/**
 * Search devices.
 *
 * @param sn the serial number of the device
 * @param site the site of it
 * @param ipAdress the ip adress of it
 * @param installDt the install date of it
 * @param endDt the end date of it
 * @return the list of device
 */
void searchDevices(String sn, String site, String ipAdress, Date installDt, Date EndDt);
```

And finally the function that cause problem :

```
 public void searchDevices(String sn, String site, String ipAdress, Date installDt, Date EndDt) {

    System.out.println("toto");

}
```

Please advice

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that none of the following objects is null.

```
identityService
device
device.getOwner()
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the device is null or not before accessing the values

```
if(device != null)
{
   identityService.searchDevices(device.getSerialNumber(), device.getOwner().getSiteName(), device.getIpAdress(), device.getInstallDate(), device.getEndDate());
}
```

Comment: I made it, it's not the issue but I forgot this useful verification. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Either of `identityService` or `service` has not been initialized and therefore is null. Then you get a `NullPointerException` when you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

1.Plz. Confirm whether you have declared and defined the bean for identity service. (Most probably it would be @Autowired in your controller and defined as bean in your SpringBean context file) and correct the discrepancies found if any.

2. Whether Object device is null or not. If it is, then check your request headers and body (which leads to creation of Device object referenced by you).

It would be far more easy to pin point the issue if you could share whole your controller file(from where the function is called and debug point on line from where null pointer is thrown).

Comment: Hi, yes my identityService is declared, and @Autowired. the bean is declared.